# How to stop or clear a BufferedImage in Java

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to make a reset button for my java platformer game using the enter key from the keyboard.  The way that my level loads is as a `BufferedImage` object passed through a method I named `LoadImageLevel`.  What I have tried to do is simply say

```
if(key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){ LoadImageLevel(level)}
```

where level is my `BufferedImage` object storing the level.  This does reset the level upon pressing the key, but once the level is reset a few times the game gets ridiculously slow and the character can't move because it is so slow.

I'm thinking this is because every time I reset the level it just puts the images on top of each other until it's doing too much at once so it slows up the game.

I've been looking around to see if there is a way to clear out the previous BufferedImages each time I reset the level so that it only runs 1 image at a time thus keeping the game up to speed... I hope.  Unfortunately there is no `clear()` or `remove()` method in the `BufferedImage` class and I have not been able to make one.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

```
    package com.tim.neon.window;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
//import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;

//import com.tim.neon.framework.GameObject;
import com.tim.neon.framework.KeyInput;
import com.tim.neon.framework.ObjectId;
import com.tim.neon.objects.Block;
import com.tim.neon.objects.Player;

//Developed by Timothy O'Leary with much help from RealTutsGML

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5023365827045558937L;

    private boolean running = false;
    private Thread thread;

    public static int WIDTH, HEIGHT;

    private BufferedImage level = null;  

    Handler handler;
    Camera cam;

    Random rand = new Random();

    private void init(){
        WIDTH = getWidth();
        HEIGHT = getHeight();

        BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();
        level = loader.loadImage("/level2.png");//loading the level

        handler = new Handler();

        cam = new Camera(0, 0);

        LoadImageLevel(level);

        this.addKeyListener(new KeyInput(handler));



    }

    public synchronized void start(){
        if(running)
            return;

        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();

    }

    public void run(){

        init(); //
        this.requestFocus(); //
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int updates = 0;
        int frames = 0;
        while(running){
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while(delta >= 1){
                tick();
                updates++;
                delta--;
            }
            render();
            frames++;

            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS: " + frames + " Ticks: " + updates);
                frames = 0;
                updates = 0;
            }
        }   
    }

    private void tick(){
        handler.tick();
        for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
            if(handler.object.get(i).getId() == ObjectId.Player){
                cam.tick(handler.object.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    private void render(){
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null){
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        //////////////////////////

        //draw here
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        g2d.translate(cam.getX(), cam.getY());//begin of cam

        handler.render(g);

        g2d.translate(-cam.getX(), -cam.getY());//end of cam
        /////////////////////////
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();

    }

    private void LoadImageLevel(BufferedImage image){//function to load levels drawn pixel by pixel in paint
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();
        System.out.println("width, height:" + " " + w + " " + h);

        for(int xx = 0; xx < h; xx++){
            for(int yy = 0; yy < w; yy++){
                int pixel = image.getRGB(xx, yy);
                int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
                int green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
                int blue = (pixel) & 0xff;

                if(red == 255 && green == 255 && blue == 255) handler.addObject(new Block(xx*32, yy*32, ObjectId.Block));
                if(red == 0 && green == 0 && blue == 255) handler.addObject(new Player(xx*32, yy*32,handler, ObjectId.Player));
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Window(800, 600, "Neon Platform Game Prototype", new Game());
    }
}
    package com.tim.neon.framework;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import com.tim.neon.objects.Block;
import com.tim.neon.objects.Player;
import com.tim.neon.window.BufferedImageLoader;
import com.tim.neon.window.Game;
import com.tim.neon.window.BufferedImageLoader;
import com.tim.neon.window.Handler;
import com.tim.neon.window.Game;
import com.tim.neon.window.Window;

public class KeyInput extends KeyAdapter {

    Handler handler;

    //public BufferedImage level = null;//i added

    public KeyInput(Handler handler){
        this.handler = handler;
    }


    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        //BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();///
        //level = loader.loadImage("/level2.png");//loading the level///

        for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
            GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

            if(tempObject.getId() == ObjectId.Player){
                if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D) tempObject.setVelX(5);
                if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A) tempObject.setVelX(-5);
                if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && !tempObject.isJumping()){//for double jump do if(key == KeyEvent.VK.SPACE) tempObject.setVelY(-15)
                    tempObject.setJumping(true);
                    tempObject.setVelY(-15);//change number to increase or decrease jump height
                }
            }
        }

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
            System.exit(1);
        }
        //if(key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){/// trying to make reset button
        //  level.repaint();
        //}///
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
int key = e.getKeyCode();

        for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
            GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

            if(tempObject.getId() == ObjectId.Player){
                if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D) tempObject.setVelX(0);
                if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A) tempObject.setVelX(0);
            }
        }
    }

    /*private void LoadImageLevel(BufferedImage image){// this function is used in both this clas and the Game class
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();
        System.out.println("width, height:" + " " + w + " " + h);

        for(int xx = 0; xx < h; xx++){
            for(int yy = 0; yy < w; yy++){
                int pixel = image.getRGB(xx, yy);
                int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
                int green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
                int blue = (pixel) & 0xff;

                if(red == 255 && green == 255 && blue == 255) handler.addObject(new Block(xx*32, yy*32, ObjectId.Block));
                if(red == 0 && green == 0 && blue == 255) handler.addObject(new Player(xx*32, yy*32,handler, ObjectId.Player));
            }
        }
    }*/

}
```

Comment: For help sooner, please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It's unlikely that your game is slow because of re rendering of images. Check the memory utilization of the game as you play it. Most likely you're not freeing allocated memory when moving to next level.

Comment: Just added the two main classes I'm trying to use to to make this reset button.  KeyInput and Game.

Comment: And yes, you are probably right it's pretty messy and I'm most likely not allocating memory efficiently.  Thanks for the interest

Comment: What is the size of the image you are using? And how many block are you drawing?

Comment: image is 1.17kb and its about 300 blocks give or take

Comment: In the LoadImageLevel(BufferedImage image){} function that is commented out at the bottom of the KeyInput class I took away the if statement that adds blocks and left the if statement that adds the player.  Then I called that function in if(key == KeyEvent_ENTER) it works much better than what I was trying before. The player still doesn't move as smooth as I'd like though